# Customizing Header of a Web API Requests via JQuery/JavaScript (AJAX) or WinForms

Tags: c#, jquery, httpwebrequest, http-headers, asp.net-web-api

I am learning and using **Web API** and need to implement following **Authentication mechanism**:

> Very First call to Web API will be a Handshaking (**Login and token
>   sharing**). Login Method of the Web API will be called with the proper
>   credentials, **once approved a GUID based Token will be returned** to the
>   Client( A Jquery or Windows based). Token will be **expired** after some
>   configurable time.
>
> Till then, **client should be able to communicate with the WebAPI with
>   sharing the same token value with every requests**, thus wouldn't need
>   to authenticate each call.
>
> For having Token in each call, it is quite possible to have it in each
>   QueryString or have it in each param of the Web API method.

But, I am looking for the possibilities Where **Token can be embedded with the HTTPRequestHeader via JQuery (using AJAX calls) or Windows based clients.** I would like if you guys could help me to identify the fair approach to implement this system and perils in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the headers in jQuery using [`beforeSend method`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) when using jQuery Ajax.

Adding / Modifying HTTP Request Headers using [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is no problem.

Maybe [Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Http](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Http) will support your described scenario soon: [Thread: Web API Sample for Thinktecture.IdentityModel at WebApiContrib Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/webapicontrib/qbBxR-8MvAY/MIP5E4LSfGcJ)

Some token based authentication mechanism like SWT and SAML 1.1 / 2.0 are already implemented in Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Http.

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTTP authentication which uses plain text to send user name and password, so to protect it you could use SSL.

An excellent article could be found [here](http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-membership-provider/)

Comment: That will completely change the way of implementing the Authentication in the target Web API. I need to follow the decided protocols.